# onPostExecute not executing; doInBackground working fine

Tags: java, android

I have read the many similar posts on this subject, and none have helped me.

I have an AsynkTask class that is performing its work just fine, but for some reason the onPostExecute method is never executed.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
public class MyPublicClass
{
    private class MonitorAudioTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ParseResult>
    {
        @Override
        protected ParseResult doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            // set variables
            ParseResult result = null;

            // do stuff
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ParseResult result)
        {
            if (result != null)
            {
                // deal with result
            }

            //Now start the task again
            _task = new MonitorAudioTask();
            _task.execute(null, null, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Again, the doInBackground method is working perfectly fine.  I have done logging at the very end of it (right before the return statement) to prove that it is functioning properly.

The ParseResult class is dead simple and also proven to be working fine.

I've proven that the onPostExecute is not being performed by doing dome debug logging on the first line of that method.

Any advice would be MOST welcome as I am curently bashing my head in and not getting anywhere.

Thanks.

**EDIT**:

I should also mention that I took development of this app over from a previous developer.  And this app USED to work fine. Two things happened between it working and it not working:
1) I made a couple minor tweaks to a function that is called from within the doInBackground() method.
2) It looks like the previous developer was working on an older version of ADT (JellyBean 4.1.2), and I have installed the latest version: 4.3.

Again, thanks for your help.

**UPDATE**:
I just updated my ADT to have the 4.1.2 SDK so I can develop on the same version the previous programmer was on.  I ran my test again, and pretty much the same thing happened.
The only difference is that eventually I got a "the app is not responding" message from the app.
So it looks like doInBackground() is returning its output, but then that is kinda crashing the app.
Does this help explain what's happening to me?

**UPDATE**:
I just ran another where I moved all of my debugging calls to be made from within the onProgress() method.  I wanted to make sure that my debugging code wasn't getting in the way.  Interesting result: NONE of the debugging calls were made.  So it looks like neither onProgress nor onPostExecute was executed.

Comment: Any chance the doInBackground is stuck somewhere?

Comment: Sadly nope.  I have verified that it does everything it should and makes it ALL the way through its work.  I did a debug logging RIGHT before the return statement.

Comment: Any chance you're canceling the task with the cancel() method?
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute(Result)

Comment: nope.  Not that either..  Keep 'em coming though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found my problem: I was doing a debug call in the first line of the onPostExecute() method.  The problem is that this particular debug call makes a web service call to post the message to my server. And apparently those types of calls are NOT allowed inside the onPostExecute() method.

So once I removed my debug code, things started to work again.

Thank you all for your help and time.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Android are you working on? If it is Pre JellyBean, you need to execute AsyncTask from the UI Thread. From JB onwards, AsyncTasks are loaded in UI thread by the framework.

If you are not loading AsyncTask in UI thread, onPostExecute wont be invoked. The other reason could be `onPostExecute` wont be invoked if the task was cancelled.

Comment: Development on this app began with android 4.1.2 (JellyBean), and I am now working in an android 4.3 environment.  As far as where this code is happening, to be fair I'm newish to android development and picked this app up from a previous developer.  It is an app with many java files handling UI stuff.  And this code exists in one of those files.  This code DID used to work.  Most notably, its behavior changed when I installed the new ADT. Any thoughts?  Thanks!

Comment: This is not related to ADT updates for sure. ADT just provides the set of tools for Android development. It is more to do with the code side, you can check whether you are starting the asynctask from the main ui thread. But in your case, as you are using JB, the framework takes care of executing asynctask in ui thread.

Answer (score 0):

I think, that such behavior happened because you've deleted the call to method of super class. Add this statement on top of your code in onPostExecute and everything should be fine again:

```
super.onPostExecute(result);
```